# Why do I need "sys.argv" to start a QApplication in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, command-line-arguments, qapplication

I try to understand what PyQt does. And one of the first things I didn't, was:

```
QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Why do I have to give QApplication this argument? I know what `sys.argv` does. But in my Scripts I wouldn't need it.

Comment: + 1 for being curious and asking questions, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713006/elegant-command-line-argument-parsing-for-pyqt

Comment: +1 for curiosity i like these kind of questions that asker wants to understand **Why the code works** instead of **Why the code doesn't work** it's really sad after 5 years of being on stackoverflow i see these questions don't get the love that they deserve (Saw some of them downvoted in some cases!!!) probably because most of coders only want the code to work it works job done. These quesions are more valuable than those What is the solution or Why there is an error in my code kind of quesions.

Comment: ...oops... I've upvoted by a non-accident ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This calls the constructor of the C++ class `QApplication`. It uses `sys.argv` (`argc` and `argv` in C++) to initialize the QT application. There are a bunch of arguments that you can pass to QT, like styles, debugging stuff and so on.

Take a look at [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication) for a full list of the options.

Comment: Is it not possible in C++ to give a default argument? 
So i have to insert always an empty list
But i think, i will survive this.

Comment: @TobiasObermayer It is, but this is a convention in QT. Don't pass an empty list, pass the real `sys.argv`. At the very least it contains the name of the executable, which QT may or may not use.

Comment: If you start a GUI from an almost empty other script it fails at commandline. cus sys.argv are not the same I guess. At least the filenames are different and startup of app seems to be refused.

Answer (score 7):

`QApplication` takes a list of strings as input.

So you can forward sys.argv or simply an empty list:

```
app = QApplication([])
```