# Why does QtWidgets.QApplication require sys.argv?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, sys

Hello guys i am learning pyqt5 from a series of tutorials at youtube and i didn't get why `QtWidgets.QApplication` have the argument `sys.argv` i am not familiar with `sys` library i read the documentation but still have no clue so sorry i know this question is kind of a noobish.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is sys.argv used for in python PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088269/what-is-sys-argv-used-for-in-python-pyqt4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need "sys.argv" to start a QApplication in PyQt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940378/why-do-i-need-sys-argv-to-start-a-qapplication-in-pyqt)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html):

> sys.argv
>
> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0] is the empty string.
>
> To loop over the standard input, or the list of files given on the command line, see the fileinput module.

Example:

```
python foo.py
sys.argv = ['foo.py']

python foo.py bar baz
sys.argv = ['foo.py', 'bar', 'baz']
```

For your specific question, see this link: [Why do I need "sys.argv" to start a QApplication in PyQt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940378/why-do-i-need-sys-argv-to-start-a-qapplication-in-pyqt)

Basically, a QT application can take initialization arguments from the command line, the top answer should point you to a list of them with an explanation of what they do.

Comment: "i didn't get why QtWidgets.QApplication have the argument sys.argv". While this answer does state what is `sys.argv`, it does *not* explain why `QtWidgets.QApplication` requires it as an argument.

Comment: Edit contains answer. The old title was unclear. This should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Why answer a question based only on the title?

Comment: "have the argument sys.argv i am not familiar with sys library i read the documentation but still have no clue so sorry i know this question is kind of a noobish."

I thought an explanation of what sys.v was and the implications when it was used as the arguments to a constructor were fairly obvious.  My bad, I have clarified.

Comment: so sys.argv is basicly what i use in my discord bot e.g. !bot_name play <link>

Comment: Essentially. When you're using the command line, you often need to pass arguments to the program you're calling (e.g copy needs a place to copy from and a place to copy to). One of the things the sys library allows you to do is use arguments passed in when your program is called inside your python code.

Comment: @walrus. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36093536/984421) to the other duplicate I lnked to. It should make everything clear.